# Tailwind preprocessor - classes from database

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using tailwind and laravel (webpack.mix.js). When running `npm run watch` (or any other compile command), all css classes which I use inside the code are compiled and working.

Since I am using tailwind classes inside the content (coming from the database) as well, I am missing some class, which aren't used inside the blade.php files and therefore aren't added to `public/css/app.css`.

Is there a way to add them by hand? Maybe some of the config files?

Comment: Have you tried to look into the Safe List? https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html#safelisting

Comment: Yes. This solved my issue back then. Maybe I should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is safelisting (https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html)

You can add a list of classes, you always want to include into your `tailwind.config.js`. For example:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: {
        content: [
            './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
            ...
        ],
        safelist: [
            "bg-color-5", "bg-color-8"
        ]
    },
    ....
}
```